# ASP MVC clear model.var1 value after invalid modelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, modelstate

After posting form If there is any error(model.IsValid==false) I want to clear 1 variable value
but it is not working

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(]VMRegister model)
    { 
        if (model.Captcha == string.Empty || model.Captcha.Trim().ToLower() != Session["CAPTCHA"].ToString())
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Captcha", "Invalid captcha entered.");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //Insert to DB
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

        /********************************
        If model state is invalid, it populates old values in form
        I want to clear captcha value, as new captcha will be appeared
        model.Captcha = string.Empty; is not working
        *********************************/
        model.Captcha = string.Empty;            
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: `ModelState.Remove("Captcha")` not working, still old value comes in textbox

Comment: Simple you can change it Like that.
model.Captcha = string.Empty;
  
  ModelState.Clear();
  return View(model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write both

```
ModelState.Remove("Captcha");
model.Captcha = string.Empty;
```

Hope this will work